# Bot Framework bot works in Emulator but gets Microsoft.Bot.ChannelConnector.BotAPI.ThrowOnFailedStatusCode on deployed bot

Tags: node.js, typescript, azure, botframework

I'm using the bot framework v4. When I test my bot locally using the emulator it works fine. When I deployed my bot and try to access it using the direct line or web chat no messages show up and when I try to send the bot a message it fails. In the Channels health I get "There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code InternalServerError"

Application Insights shows an Exception that says "POST to  failed: POST to the bot's endpoint failed with HTTP status 500 POST to the bot's endpoint failed with HTTP status 500"

This is the call stack

```
   at Microsoft.Bot.ChannelConnector.BotAPI+<PostActivityToBotAsync>d__31.MoveNext (Microsoft.Bot.Base.ChannelConnector, Version=3.2.3.8, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
Inner exception System.Exception handled at Microsoft.Bot.ChannelConnector.BotAPI+<PostActivityToBotAsync>d__31.MoveNext:
   at Microsoft.Bot.ChannelConnector.BotAPI.ThrowOnFailedStatusCode (Microsoft.Bot.Base.ChannelConnector, Version=3.2.3.8, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
   at Microsoft.Bot.ChannelConnector.BotAPI+<PostActivityToBotAsync>d__31.MoveNext (Microsoft.Bot.Base.ChannelConnector, Version=3.2.3.8, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
```

I've been able to get the bot working before. I recently made a new bot on my Azure account and it's working fine.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you recent made a bot purely on azure, and it works, but this bot is created locally and deployed, but doesn't, then something went sideways in the deployment. How did you deploy your bot?

Comment: Hi @JJ_Wailes I deployed it using ```az webapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group "<resouce-group-name>" --name "<bot-resource-name>" --src "allfiles.zip" ```

Comment: This is the way I've previously deployed it

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: Yes I am still working on it

Comment: We're going to need some more information to diagnose your issue. Are you using memory storage? Can you try debugging the code locally while still connecting to Web Chat with [ngrok](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/19/debug-channel-locally-using-ngrok/)?

Comment: @KyleDelaney I've used Memory Storage on previous deployments and they work. On this deployment  I've changed the Memory Storage to use Cosmos DB. I am able to deploy the older version of my code and they work fine. I'm working on getting ngrok now

Comment: @123me - If you continue to use memory storage in deployed bots, you will likely start to encounter issues that are very hard to diagnose. Memory storage is not an option for deployed bots, even if the bots seem to be working for now.

Comment: @KyleDelaney I tried running with ngrok deployed locally and got nothing. I also tried connecting with the Emulator to my bot deployed on Azure and got an error saying 'An error occured while POSTing"/INSPECT open" command to Conversation xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|livechat

Comment: @123me - What do you mean when you say you "got nothing"? Are you saying you ran your bot in debug mode locally and connected to the bot in Web Chat using ngrok but you didn't encounter the 500 error? So Web Chat works fine using a tunneled ngrok endpoint but not when using a deployed Azure Websites endpoint?

Comment: @123me - Are you still working on this?

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to a [bug](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/11390) in the commands `az bot prepare-deploy` and `az webapp deployment source config-zip`. As a workaround, try manually correcting the name of your assembly in your .deployment file as described [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/issues/1993#issuecomment-558394081) and then redeploy.

Comment: I wrote my bot in Typescript the `az bot prepare-deploy` command doesn't need a `--proj-file-path` instead it uses a src folder instead of a .csproj

Comment: @123me - Okay, but what's in your .deployment file?

Comment: This is in my .deployment file `[config]
SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true`